# Как получить и отправить в метод элементы массива под определенным индексом

Tags: html, angular

Есть БД, откуда приходит информация, которая выводится через *ngFor в HTML. Нужно получить и отправить в сервис только ту часть, которая находится в элементе, а не всю.
Когда нажимаю кнопку, то должен получить только информацию данного блока:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужны вот эти данные [0], а не все:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и так далее по анологии, каждый блок отвечает за свою информацию.

HTML:

```html
<div class="col" *ngFor="let db of clothesdb, let i = index">
  <div class="card shadow-sm">
    <span class="text-center "><strong>{{db.name}}</strong></span>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{db.image}}" alt="Sad image didn't load" width="100%" height="400">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Цена:{{db.price}}</p>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="getProductInfo(db[i])">Посмотреть</button>
        </div>
        <small class="text-muted">{{db.vendorCode}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
 getProductInfo( infoProduct:Clothes){
    this.clothesService.getProduct(infoProduct);
    console.log(this.clothesdb);
  }
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: А что у вас метод `getProductInfo` делает?

Comment: Чисто выводит туда вложенный обьект и передает в сервис.

Comment: так вы уже это делаете без индекса, ваша db уже и есть тот самый элемент массива. `getProductInfo(db)`

Comment: или так `getProductInfo(clothesdb[i])`

Comment: Немного в этом случае затупил, ибо индекс писал к db, а не к clothesdb. Напишите ваш ответ, чтобы я пометил это как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как используется конструкция ngFor, то получается в каждой итерации уже используется только нужный объект. Поэтому индекс тут не нужен, достаточно просто передать db - `getProductInfo(db)`

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let db of clothesdb, let i = index">
  <div class="card shadow-sm">
          ...
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="getProductInfo(db)">Посмотреть</button>
  </div>
</div>
```